# how to differentiate layouts files (.xml files ) in different-different layout folders in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

how to differentiate layouts files  (.xml files ) in different-different layout folders in Android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean differenciate by portrait/landscape?

```
layout-land/
layout-port/
```

You can read more about this here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

There are more possibilities like:

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

You can read more here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html